# Visio Master shape being overwritten when added to the page

Tags: visio

I have created a visio master shape that shows fields from the shape property (Name, Title, Department, type). I add all the fields to be displayed on the shape and it looks fine on the master shape, but once I add the shape to the page, it only shows the first two fields (name, title). It seems to be reverting back to a default I can't get rid of, is there anything on the shape sheet that I can edit to remove this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Anag

Comment: Have you cleared the document stencil?  Not sure how you're going about developing the shape, but if you had used a prior version in the same document before, the document stencil holds onto the original until you clear it...

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck the "**Match master name on drop**" option in the master's properties.
When checked, it forces the behavior you describe (reuses old master if exists)